# GET(url) returns error

Tags: r, httr

When I use below command

```
url = 'www.somesite.com'
GET(url)
```

I get below error - I am not sure what it relates to.

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  easy handled already used in multi handle
```

Comment: You should try to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Your code does not produce the error you describe.

Comment: I restarted R session and I guess it fixed the problem ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **RCurl** directly this works without error:

```
> RCurl::httpGET('www.somesite.com')
[1] "    <html data-adblockkey=\"MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANHZLSNGAhe0lWbSycFlY7t3c4tFHP+Epw8naGgm3CR8CftAihnB7Jkt+vFmvIf3BV/p3RpOrZ/XbZsX9uh0m9UCAwEAAQ==_jJgyGlO27u/CWR1xPtVqducj4Y1JMgxGGKTmh0wKT2NiLTbZW1DUVt7xP5VsCa0q5F4+744tv9exTeUO7nf6tQ==\"> \n\n<head>\n        <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n    <title>SomeSite.com: The Leading Some Site Site on the Net</title>\n            <script type=\"text/javascript\">;\n        if(self != top) top.location.href = 'http://'+location.hostname+'/?redir=frame&uid=www5301308f09b0e8.72483303';\n        </script>\n        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://return.bs.domainnamesales.com/return_js.php?d=somesite.com&s=1392586895\"></script>\n\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n        function GetParam(name) {\n            var match = new RegExp(name +  \n                \"=*([^&]+)*\", \"i\").exec(location.search);   \n            if (match == null)             \n                match = new RegExp(name + \"=(.+)\", \"i\").exec(location.search);  \n            if (match == null) return null;             \n                match = match + \"\";           \n            //**convert match to a string       \n            result = match.split(\",\");          \n            return decodeURIComponent(result[1]);     \n        }  \n\n        function logStatus(type) {   \n            $.ajax({         \n                cache: false, \n                global: false,  \n                async: true,    \n                type: \"POST\",  \n                url: '/logpstatus.php',\n                data: {uid: GetParam('uid'), type: type}  \n            });                \n        }        \n    </script>\n\n    </head>\n    <frameset cols=\"1,*,1\" border=0>\n        <frame name=\"top\" src=\"tg.php?uid=www5301308f09b0e8.72483303\" scrolling=no frameborder=0 noresize framespacing=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0>\n        <frame src=\"search_caf.php?uid=www5301308f09b0e8.72483303&src=linen&abp=1\" scrolling=\"auto\" framespacing=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 noresize>\n        <frame src=\"page.php?www5301308f09b0e8.72483303\"></frame>\n    </frameset>\n    <noframes>\n        somesite.com has been connecting our visitors with providers of Build A Web Site, Cheap Web Design, Create Web Sites and many other related services for nearly 10 years. Join thousands of satisfied visitors who found Ecommerce Web Design, Flash Web Design, Graphic Web Design, Multimedia Designs, and Search Engine Optimization.<br/>    </noframes>\n</html>\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to specify the protocol.

```
url = 'http://www.somesite.com'; GET(url)
```